# What is the best way to connect two users with credit card for payments on the web site?

Tags: e-commerce, paypal, authorize

What is the best way to allow one site user to pay to another user, through web site using credit card?

What is best fits for this Paypal Pro or Authorize.net?

Comment: FYI, if you ask a question you should do your best to choose a best answer. You have failed to do so in your two previous questions. You'll find members will be less likely to provide answers if you don't give back to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with Authorize.Net or Paypal Payments Pro because they offer no service for this. If you are a US based merchant, and you have to be to use Authorize.Net, you can't use your merchant account to accept payments on behalf of another businesses. It is called factoring and will result in your merchant account being shut down and your business, and you, being added to [the Match File](http://www.merchant-account-services.org/blog/what-is-the-match-file/) which is a blacklist that prevents you from ever having your own merchant account again. T

To accomplish this you will either need to use something like Paypal's split payments or force your users to all have Authorize.Net accounts. If they all have Authnet accounts you can dynamically use their accounts to process payments. However this means you will not be able to deduct any fees fro the transaction and will need to run another transaction to charge your users any fees incurred for providing your services.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the transaction to go via your website, you would need to accept the payment from User A and then generate a payment to User B. This would mean the resulting payment would end up some 5 or 6 percent lower by the time you've paid for payment fees.

Alternatively, you could set up the payment to be direct from User A to User B, with PayPal you'd essentially be brokering a "payment to an email address" and it would then occur via PayPal rather than via your website. This method would essentially remove you from the process and possibly even protect you from charge-backs / payment disputes.